# JSON not parsing, throwing exception

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net

I'm getting JSON from a server in string format and I am saving it to a text file

Then I'm reading that text file and giving it back to the server but there I'm not able to parse it back to an object.  It may be because the escape sequence are causing the problem or I don't know.

Please suggest, I'm using C# and  Newtonsoft's JSON.NET

Here are the samples:

String received from server and saving this to local txt file

```
{"data":"[{\"MenuId\":483,\"Name\":\"Nikhil menu\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"ASAP\":\"T\",\"LT\":\"T\",\"FO\":\"T\",\"catList\":[{\"CatId\":5132,\"CatName\":\"Cate00\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"P1\":{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"SML\"},\"P2\":{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"MED\"},\"P3\":null,\"P4\":null,\"P5\":null,\"P6\":null,\"CatType\":\"Normal\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Id\":38190,\"Name\":\"XXX\",\"Desc\":\"tesdt\",\"MinQ\":1,\"MaxQ\":99,\"MinP\":0.0,\"MaxP\":0.0,\"P1\":100.0,\"P2\":200.0,\"P3\":-99.0,\"P4\":-99.0,\"P5\":-99.0,\"P6\":-99.0,\"Img\":\"\",\"Icon1\":null,\"Icon2\":null,\"Icon3\":null,\"Icon4\":null,\"OpenOn\":{\"Mon\":\"T\",\"Tue\":\"T\",\"Wed\":\"T\",\"Thu\":\"T\",\"Fri\":\"T\",\"Sat\":\"T\",\"Sun\":\"T\"},\"SpecialOffer\":null,\"AddOnList\":[],\"ItemModList\":[]}]}]}]","message":"Processed Successfully","serviceName":"CreateCache","serviceStatus":"S"}
```

string after reading the same local text file from the server

```
{"data":"[{\"MenuId\":483,\"Name\":\"Nikhil menu\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"ASAP\":\"T\",\"LT\":\"T\",\"FO\":\"T\",\"catList\":[{\"CatId\":5132,\"CatName\":\"Cate00\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"P1\":{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"SML\"},\"P2\":{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"MED\"},\"P3\":null,\"P4\":null,\"P5\":null,\"P6\":null,\"CatType\":\"Normal\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Id\":38190,\"Name\":\"XXX\",\"Desc\":\"tesdt\",\"MinQ\":1,\"MaxQ\":99,\"MinP\":0.0,\"MaxP\":0.0,\"P1\":100.0,\"P2\":200.0,\"P3\":-99.0,\"P4\":-99.0,\"P5\":-99.0,\"P6\":-99.0,\"Img\":\"\",\"Icon1\":null,\"Icon2\":null,\"Icon3\":null,\"Icon4\":null,\"OpenOn\":{\"Mon\":\"T\",\"Tue\":\"T\",\"Wed\":\"T\",\"Thu\":\"T\",\"Fri\":\"T\",\"Sat\":\"T\",\"Sun\":\"T\"},\"SpecialOffer\":null,\"AddOnList\":[],\"ItemModList\":[]}]}]}]","message":"Processed Successfully","serviceName":"CreateCache","serviceStatus":"S"}
```

string which I get after adding it to and object of another class which I use to send it over again to server and I get this string on server

```
{"data":"[{\"MenuId\":483,\"Name\":\"Nikhil menu\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"ASAP\":\"T\",\"LT\":\"T\",\"FO\":\"T\",\"catList\":[{\"CatId\":5132,\"CatName\":\"Cate00\",\"Desc\":\"test\",\"P1\":{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"SML\"},\"P2\":{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"MED\"},\"P3\":null,\"P4\":null,\"P5\":null,\"P6\":null,\"CatType\":\"Normal\",\"ItemList\":[{\"Id\":38190,\"Name\":\"XXX\",\"Desc\":\"tesdt\",\"MinQ\":1,\"MaxQ\":99,\"MinP\":0.0,\"MaxP\":0.0,\"P1\":100.0,\"P2\":200.0,\"P3\":-99.0,\"P4\":-99.0,\"P5\":-99.0,\"P6\":-99.0,\"Img\":\"\",\"Icon1\":null,\"Icon2\":null,\"Icon3\":null,\"Icon4\":null,\"OpenOn\":{\"Mon\":\"T\",\"Tue\":\"T\",\"Wed\":\"T\",\"Thu\":\"T\",\"Fri\":\"T\",\"Sat\":\"T\",\"Sun\":\"T\"},\"SpecialOffer\":null,\"AddOnList\":[],\"ItemModList\":[]}]}]}]","message":"Processed Successfully","serviceName":"CreateCache","serviceStatus":"S"}
```

I am not able to parse this string file back to List

I have tried

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(obj.cacheInfo.cData);
JToken jT = jObject["data"];
List<Menu> lMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Menu>>(jT.ToString());

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(obj.cacheInfo.cData);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jObject["data"].ToString());
```

any help will do, thanks

Comment: In the title you mention there is an exception - which exception?

Comment: According the http://jsonlint.com/ that is valid JSON. Does your parser enforce any encoding schemes (like UTF-8) for JSON and are you reading/writing/transmitting with that proper scheme? What is the error text?

Comment: Are all members of the "obj" public or you have some protected?

Comment: is there any reason your not escaping the quotes here : `"message":"Processed Successfully","serviceName":"CreateCache","serviceStatus":"S"}`

Comment: Error converting value "[{"MenuId":483,"Name":"Nikhil menu","Desc":"test","ASAP":"T","LT":"T{"Mon":"T","Tue":"T","Wed":"T","Thu":"T","Fri":"T","Sat":"T","Sun":"T"},"SpecialOffer":null,"AddOnList":[],"ItemModList":[]}]}]}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Menu]'.

Comment: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String

Comment: @AdamSweeney you can see that the escaping sequence only in list under data key, rest there is no escaping seq

Comment: @JAAulde it is valid but if you see the value of data key is having escaping sequence which is why the value is not getting parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of the JSON.NET library on the servers. On one server it was 3.5 and other one it was 4.5. Thanx all for all of your support.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but have you tried accepting a collection of `Menu` as an array? I'm not sure if Json.NET automatically converts a JavaScript array of `T` to a `List<T>`. Try this:

```
List<Menu> lMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Menu[]>(jT.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: it is deserialized from List<menu>

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support `List<T>` natively, meaning although it was serialised from a `List<T>` doesn't necessarily mean it'll de-serialise to a `List<T>`. Did you try `T[]`?

Comment: Thnx... doing it this way now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the properties are public.
Make sure class you deserializing has default constructor.
The arrays in the class - how are they implemented ?
And yeah, which exception ?